# Download state disappears on reload

Tags: swift, download

I have a download function that downloads files from a website. Everything works great except for when I click on the back button from the navigation controller and try to reload the view controller. The download task runs fine in the background but resets the view on the second reload. Here's my code.

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask,
                didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64,
                totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
    // 1
    guard let url = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url,
        let download = downloadService.activeDownloads[url]  else { return }
    // 2
    download.progress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
    // 3
    let totalSize = ByteCountFormatter.string(fromByteCount: totalBytesExpectedToWrite,
                                              countStyle: .file)

    // 4
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let myCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: Int(download.resource.resourceId - 1) ,
                                                                   section: 0)) as? TranslationViewCell {
            myCell.updateDisplay(progress: download.progress, totalSize: totalSize)
            if download.isDownloading == true{
                myCell.downloadButton.isHidden = true //this doesnt get activated at all. 
                myCell.reloadInputViews()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to keep the download button hidden if the download is running in the background.

Answer (score 2):

When a view controller gets popped off the stack it gets deallocated. This means that the 'self' you reference in the code no longer exists, which makes it impossible to update the view.

In order to load up the view correctly the second time, you need to be holding onto the download task in code that does not get deallocated or use something like events to respond to the download task itself.

We could devolve into an entire discussion of iOS app architecture at this point; however I'll give you my favorite option to just get this working.

Send a Notification rather than interacting with the tableview directly. The code might look something like this...

First extend the notification class for your own app:

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let downloadProgressChanged = Notification.Name("download_progress_changed")
}
```

Then post the notification during the callback:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let notificationDict:[String: Download] = ["download": download]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .downloadProgressChanged, object: nil, userInfo: userDict)
}
```

Then your view controller will need to listen for those notifications and update themselves appropriately, you should probably call this in viewDidLoad

```
    // MARK - Notifications
func setupListeners() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleProgressChanged(notification:)), name: .downloadProgressChanged, object: nil)
}

@objc func handleProgressChanged(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let download = notification.userInfo?["download"] as? <whatever the class of Download is> {
        // update the tableview here
    }
}
```

Now you have a view controller that can respond to this download task appropriately without needing to know anything about the task at all.